javascript scroll width conflict
as my logic entails, if scrollPosition  services.length - 3  cardWidth this is the logic to handle the  card scroll. but on my browser when i click the right button the animation moves but the previous card is  visible by a fraction and the visibility continues increasing as you keep on scrollingenter image description here
  const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.fa-arrow-left');
  const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.fa-arrow-right');

  if (servicesContainer && services.length > 0) {
    const cardStyle = window.getComputedStyle(services[0]);
    const cardWidth = services[0].offsetWidth + parseInt(cardStyle.marginRight);
    let scrollPosition = 0;

    function scrollServices(direction) {
      if (direction === 'left') {
        if (scrollPosition > 0) {
          scrollPosition -= cardWidth;
        } else {
          servicesContainer.style.animation = 'pushAnimation 0.3s ease';
          setTimeout(() => {
            servicesContainer.style.animation = '';
          }, 300);
        }
      } else if (direction === 'right') {
        if (scrollPosition < (services.length - 3) * cardWidth) { // 3 visible cards
          scrollPosition += cardWidth;
        } else {
          servicesContainer.style.animation = 'pushAnimationRight 0.3s ease';
          setTimeout(() => {
            servicesContainer.style.animation = '';
          }, 300);
        }
      }
      servicesContainer.scrollTo({
        left: scrollPosition,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }

    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => scrollServices('left'));
    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => scrollServices('right'));
  } else {
    console.error('Services container or services elements not found.');
  }
});


here is the css handling the cards 

.services .service {
      background: var(--white);
      flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 3); /* Ensure each .service element takes up 30% of the container width */
      min-height: 400px;
      padding: 40px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin-right: 10px; /* Ensure consistent right margin */
      opacity: 0; /* Ensure elements are initially hidden */
      animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out forwards; /* Apply the animation */
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}```




here is the css handling the cards 


the code works but has a minor issue i would appreciate any suggestions 

i'm expecting a full flow of the button in relation to the website

